Looking for an animated short film from the 90s
I am looking for an animated short film from the 1990s that aired in the early 90s on the French channel Canal+.  It was in color, 2D animation, similar in style to Disney but not Disney.
The short film narrates the story of two music instruments that try to seduce each other.  The instruments are made to look "human" with eyes and mouth, etc. The "woman" is a violin or a cello, I think, whereas the "male" is a saxophone or a muted trumpet. The two characters evolve in a large ballroom lit by the evening sun.  They never talk with words, instead, they seem to talk, but it's music that comes out. So, when the saxophone "talks" to the cello, it's actually sax music coming out of him.  
The technique used to make the characters talk isn't very different from this scene from Chairman of the Board with Jerry Lewis.
Only, with instruments instead of humans, which made the film go from a very jazzy soundtrack when the cocky saxophone was playing, to classical when the violin was playing. The style of drawing was close to Disney, but not Disney, somewhat similar to this (this is from Disney's The Beauty and the Beast):

I think the short animated film might have been European or a coproduction.

Well, there is an animated short about a romance between a male sax and a female cello, but it's definitely Disney (and very old).

Bah. There's too much sax and violins on TV these days.

Yep, it's definitely not this one at all.

I have found the name of this short film (I didn't think it was possible, see note at the end of this answer).
Do Nothing Til you Hear From Me, 1994.

The film is a European animated short film from the mid-90s featuring instruments that speak in their own music with each other. The drawing style is very modern and not very far from Disney but the theme and style are more mature than the ones usually found in Disney. Unfortunately it's not online.
In order to find this answer, I thought about the following technique (I thought of this a few days after asking the question here, honestly) - and thought I'd share it here:   
-have IMDb generate a list of all the films in the category the film belongs to (to do this, Google "IMDb" + "what you're looking for" + "film", so in this example, "imdb" + "animated short")  
-organize the answers by year descending, so that the most recent films will be on top of the first page  

-start digging by changing the number in the IMDb URL to easily access the year you're looking for (add 100, 500 or 1000 to skip several dozen pages at a time)

-google everything that might be the a possible answer until you find it
-pray really hard that the film you're looking for is on IMDb, that there's a hint of a description or a poster, etc. 
Note: I often cringe when people answer their own questions. In this case, I had honestly given up on ever finding this title when I asked the question here, and after asking it on SE started thinking of new ways to search for this title I hadn't thought about before. Please leave a comment if you would like to help me improve this answer. 
Note 2: The technique I used to find the answer to this question can be used to find almost any film once you know the date and the genre and have a lot of time on your hands.

Well done, a 20 year old animated Swedish short indeed sounds hard to find. But TBH, you didn't need Google for most of this, you can just go to IMDb's advanced search directly.

Walt, good suggestion! Can you expand on this with a quick how-to? I didn't know it was Swedish. When looking in the Advanced page for animation + short film + color + 1989 to 1997, I only get 16 results! This film isn't in the list. So maybe I remove "color" or other info that the film's IMDb sheet doesn't contain. But I get what you mean! Good suggestion and good alternative... Will be helpful to solve other identification cases here.

I'm afraid that's the problem, it 1. Relies on users' input, which is sometimes lacking in obscure titles, and 2. Is clunky. For example, feeding Genre=animation, Plot=instrument and Release date=1989-1997 into it still doesn't come up with this title, even though its IMDb page clearly contains all of these elements.

(...But sometimes it does work. Try to cover as many categories as possible in it and come up with relevant terms in the 'keywords' and 'plot' boxes.)

Yeah... The technique I posted in my answer is sickeningly long and tedious, but more 100%-proof (IF the film is listed on IMDb!). Also, I've found a lot of short films I've seen by working this way, and used the occasion to add a photo - definitely a quick and useful thing to do.
